# Clustered Web Servers Failing

Tags: iis, webserver, iis-7.5

I have three web servers running Windows Server 2008. Two are clustered, the third a standalone server (two live, one test). They use shared configuration with the configuration file located on a central file server. Every so often one live web server will stop responding. The event log shows the following error.

```
The worker process for application pool 'My Website' encountered an error 'Configuration file is not well-formed XML
' trying to read configuration data from file '\\?\C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\My Website\My Website.config', line number '3'.  The data field contains the error code.
```

The config file has the following data

```
<!-- ERROR: There's been an error reading or processing the applicationhost.config file.  Line number: 0  Error message: Cannot read configuration file
 -->
```

There is nothing in the event viewer on the file server.

When I restart the web server everything works fine.

Any ideas?

### Edit

I have around 30 websites. 10 are true standalone websites running in their own application pools. The other 20 are old websites that just redirect all requests to a different URL (some on my server, some external), these share the same application pool.

One of the 10 "standalone" websites is running php. One is .NET 2.0. One is classic asp with two virtual directories set up to run as a .NET 2.0 applications. The other 7 are running classic asp only.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite old but I came here because I had this issue today and it seems to be still around. The reason is usually the DFSR feature, which is especially valid if one runs a cluster. There are three possible solutions.

- Change a registry key to reduce the speed of synchronization and avoid the file lock the leads to the error as described here:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2013/12/01/you-may-experience-configuration-file-is-not-well-formed-xml-error-while-using-dfsr-to-synchronize-the-iis-configuration-files/
- Install a Hotfix provided by Microsoft. The direct link is https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/hotfix/kbhotfix?kbnum=960412&kbln=en-US
- Configure your DFSR environment properly and exclude the folder *\inetpub\temp\apppools* explicitly (after DFSR replicated the applicationHost.config the WAS will rebuild the files anyway)

Despite the Hotfix I personally like the third option most.

---

The purpose of this late answer is documentation, as others may come here and the page seems well ranked on Google.

Comment: How does one perform the third option?

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot but...
If the file is accessed through netbios and its regularly accessed you may be hitting the fileserver too hard and windows thinks you are trying to do a DOS attack so it starts rejecting requests. This may also be caused by a firewall  interpreting this very samething when accessing the file server.

Also, from [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734988%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), check you that the temp folder for the iis user is full, the problem may not only be the file server, but failure to temporary store the config file.

Can you share some volume information of your server layout? (# application pools / # websites , etc)

Edit:

I assume you're not interested in workarounds to this, especially if it means changing the location of the file :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm currently waiting for the web servers to be rebuilt before I can have a look at your proposed solutions. I'll update the question with the server layout.

Comment: This probably isn't the answer but you might as well have the bounty. You were the only one who showed an interest!